# Word usage - So

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I saw this in a SpongeBob episode (That's no lady):

> Ok. You're fired. If someone needs me, I'll be in my office for 20 years or *so*

What does that mean? That "so"?

Comment: TL;DR; more or less 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "or so" is an idiom that means the preceding phrase is not to be taken literally. It usually is a synonym for "more or less" or "approximately." But in this case, it more likely indicates an acknowledgement of hyperbole.